Repeatedly calling an API while concurrently processing that data in C#
Looking to figure out where exactly I'm going wrong.
I have a program that queries an API, the API returns data in chunks and will return a response header with a URL to the next chunk of data, if there is more.
I'm trying to call the query the API, when I get a response, I would like to start processing that data as I'm waiting for the next chunk of data to arrive. But it seems like I'm waiting for the data, processing it and then waiting/requesting the next bunch
JArray jsonObjects = new JArray();

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    jsonObjects = await GetObjectsJSONAsync();
}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

private async Task<JArray> GetObjectsJSONAsync()
{
    /*
     * HttpClient setup here
     */

    var response = "";
    var headers = "";
    var total = 0;
    JArray productsFromURL = new JArray();
    HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync("/products/skus/");
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        headers = result.Headers.GetValues("Link").FirstOrDefault();
        response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        jsonObjectsFromURL = JArray.Parse(response);
        ProcessObjects(productsFromURL);
        while (headers.Contains("rel=\"next\"")) //while header contains next link
        {
            var url = headers.Split(';')[0].Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "");
            result = await client.GetAsync(url);
            try
            {
                response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                jsonObjectsFromURL = JArray.Parse(response);
                ProcessObjects(jsonObjectsFromURL); //adds processed objects to a ConcurrentBag
                headers = result.Headers.GetValues("Link").FirstOrDefault();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //This means that there are no more pages to get
                headers = "";
            }
        }
    }

    return jsonObjectsFromURL; //dont care about the return here
}


The code shared also violates DRY Why not design this in a way where the service solely does the fetching of the data in chunks and sends that data to a message broker where a consumer will pick this data from and process it?

About the tags: note that parallel codes are necessarily concurrent but concurrent codes are note necessarily parallel. Your code is concurrent but not parallel (at least there is no evidences of that). See this post.

@JérômeRichard the JArray.Parse is sufficient evidence IMHO that the processing is at least partially CPU-bound, so the parallel-processing tag is applicable. Parallel, concurrent and asynchronous can coexist, they are not mutually exclusive concepts.

I will assume that you can modify the GetObjectsJSONAsync so that it returns a tuple with three elements, the current URL, the next URL, and the JArray result:
private async Task<(string, string, JArray)> GetObjectsJSONAsync(string url)
{
    string nextUrl;
    JArray jsArray;
    /* ... */
    return (url, nextUrl, jsArray);
}

Now you can abstract the parallelization of invoking the GetObjectsJSONAsync and processing the JArray, using the ParallelizeTwoActions below:
/// <remarks>
/// Invokes two actions for each element in a sequence, sequentially.
/// The action1 is invoked sequentially for one element at a time.
/// The action2 is also invoked sequentially for one element at a time.
/// The action1 for an element is invoked in parallel with the action2 for its
/// previous element.
/// The action1 should return the next element in the sequence, or null if it's
/// the last element.
/// </remarks>
public static async Task ParallelizeTwoActions<TInput, TResult>(
    TInput startingInput,
    Func<TInput, Task<(TInput, TInput, TResult)>> action1,
    Func<TInput, TResult, Task> action2)
    where TInput : class
{
    if (startingInput is null) return;
    Task<(TInput, TInput, TResult)> task1 = Task.Run(() => action1(startingInput));
    Task task2 = Task.CompletedTask;
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).ConfigureAwait(false);
            (TInput previousInput, TInput nextInput, TResult result) = task1.Result;
            task2 = Task.Run(() => action2(previousInput, result));
            if (nextInput is null) break;
            task1 = Task.Run(() => action1(nextInput));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

It is a modified version of the ParallelizeTwoActions that I have posted in this older answer. That answer includes a marble diagram that demonstrates the behavior of this method.
The Task.Run ensures¹ that the two actions will be parallelized, even if they are not completely asynchronous (even if they block the current thread for a while, before returning an incomplete task). It does so by offloading the invocation of the actions to the ThreadPool.
You can use the ParallelizeTwoActions like this:
await ParallelizeTwoActions("https://stackoverflow.com", url =>
{
    return GetObjectsJSONAsync(url);
},
async (url, jsArray) =>
{
    // Process the jsArray asynchronously
});

¹ Assuming that the ThreadPool is not saturated.
